# Ariflow: dags editing by multiple users in parallel

Tags: python, airflow

We've just set up the Apache Airflow tool to schedule our jobs. I'd like to hear your feedback or best practices regarding the editing of dags by several developers.

Let me explain: we're now several people developing our own dag with different functionalities, but the problem is that there's only one 'dags' folder recognized by the airflow service.

How can I use versioning tools like git if several people are editing dags separately in a single folder?

Have you ever encountered this problem?
Thanks

Comment: can u explain more about the problem you experience ? broken dags ? performance ? resources management ? common code that you need ? also how do you deploy ? docker ? mwaa ? atronomer ?

Comment: the airflow instance is dockerized. In fact, we can't find a solution to do development together with several developers with a single airflow. Example: I'm working on the dag file 'dag-1.py' and my colleague is working on 'dag-2.py'. These 2 files are from the same repo: airflow-dags. How can I edit these 2 files in the airflow dag folder in parallel : me working on dag-1 and my collegue editing dag-2 on the same time with a version control tool like git?